# Bind to text in a text box resizes the column

Tags: wpf, mvvm, textbox, bind

I bind the `text box` to a variable that contains numbers (positive and negative) located in `ViewModel`.

when the variable changes, the size of the column that is in the `text box`, also changes (not defined size of the column)

How can I tell the column **did not change** following the text in the text box (not at all clear why this happens, if anyone knows I would love to get an answer)

some code:

xaml:

```
    <Grid Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="1" Margin="0" >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
            <RowDefinition Height="25" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="25" />
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         SOME ELEMENT
        <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Margin="3,2,0,2" Name="xName" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" Text="{Binding VM.SomeProp}"/>//THE PROPBLEM TEXTBOX
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="3,2" Name="txtblockname" Text="txt" />
    </Grid>
```

Here my prop

```
    private float _someProp;
    public float SomeProp
    {
        get { return _someProp; }
        set
        {
            if (_someProp!= value)
            {
                _someProp= value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("SomeProp");
            }
        }
    }
```

**So, the problem is when the number is negative, only then it changes the size, why is this happening at all?**

Comment: code would be helpfull, from your xaml and also you vm bindings

Comment: Set the Width property, i hope that's what it is because i'm not completely getting your questiong ;)

Comment: @jeroen It seems very strange that this happens, the text is not supposed to change the size (it does not pass the size of the text box) I was hoping there was another way to do this without having to set the size to a column, if there is no other way to put your offer as an answer. Thanks anyway

Comment: Is your text - or textbox changing size?

Comment: textbox changing size because it text change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have set a width for your Grid column.  This size will be respected but it's content can still change size.

If you don't want your textbox to change size you should set it's `Width` property.

If you do want it to change size but it has to stay withing some bounds you can use the  `Min- and MaxWidth` property.

You can also choose to stretch your textbox : `HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"` This will force it to take up all the space in the column.

Comment: I get the problem, it change the size only when it a negative number, it very strange

Comment: Another thing, does not make sense that the column moved at her left side is a constant. It's not supposed to move.